# Presets for a specific zoom in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts, zoom

Just hoping someone has figured out a shortcut (preferably keyboard shortcut) in illustrator to snap the zoom to 133% (a visual 1:1 scale for online's 72pdi).

Answer (score 4):

1. Zoom to the level you need, and click *View > New View*, give it a name like "133% view"
2. An entry will be added to the bottom of the View menu, which you can click on whenever you need that zoom level.
3. To create a shorcut for it, click *Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts*
4. Click on the drop down and change from "Tools" to "Menu Commands"
5. Click on the View menu item to expand it, and scroll down until you see "Custom View 1", add a shortcut key for it, and save your custom Keyset file with a new name.

Comment: I tried that, but the 'new'view' only seemed to save for that document. Any new document didn't retain that saved view. Even after an ai restart.

Comment: Yes views are saved in the document. So, all you need to do is create a New View once for a different document, then the shortcut key you already set up will work.

Comment: Thanks Billy, this might be as close as I get to a solution then. I was really hoping for a one-hit wonder as I create a lot of new docs, and often like to preview the work at the 133%.

Comment: @SHGDesigner Ah if only life were that simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

Quick thought: save a template file with your predefined views (and your personal branding of course) and start from that for each new file - should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script snippet. Change the zoom value for any way you like!
These days Illustrator remembers scripts as menu items in actions, if you 'install' the script in your Illustrator application's scripts folder and restart, you can now record an action and insert this script, then call it via shortcut key. Likewise you can create different scripts and their action caller buttons for multiple zoom levels.

```
function test(){
    if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {  
      app.activeDocument.views[0].zoom = 133 * (1/100);
    } 
};
test();
```

Comment: Too bad that you can not register scripts as menuitems.

Comment: To your point from a while ago, this gives more cause for a view-control script. That other thread was on topic of UI mockups, but it seems the archaic Views feature could be utilized through a custom script interface to show the right stuff. With Views, problem is they are doc-specific, but they have the shortcut key advantage. Too bad it goes by view index. Any script which auto-adds a view will have to destroy the user's custom-made views - but nobody uses it anyways. 
Maybe I can make a new notepad file and keep recording feature needs, if enough are added maybe one day I'll do this.

Comment: Too bad scripts aret first class citizens so you can not source them on stratup. Plugin time

Comment: You mean .. startup scripts? Umm, that's how I start up all my scripts.. well actually I just have it start up my own script-ui script panel which has the scripts as buttons. The issue with that setup is that you can't have shortcut keys for those, so I use AHK or Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: Well thats what i mean you can not make a well behaved script that would tie to the real GUI. ALso stratup scripts dont work in all AI versions. I can make a panel yes but it does not really help since even scriptui is a bit limited when it comes to non modal dialogs etc. Its not like scripting in many other applications that can do literally anything the gui can. On the otherhand doing this in the SDK os 4 lines of code

Comment: Absolutely. I have used non-modal dialogs, but even with those there's issues of the palette being in focus while the document isn't, plus you've got to have good BridgeTalk practice. (which I'm grateful for since it's given me a good start on cross-app scripting)
Unfortunately extensions are much more verbose and much more of a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73778/discussion-between-joojaa-and-silly-v).